# AWS.Organizations class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create a new account in an organization using the createAccount method of the AWS.Organizations class.
how do i login to this account via AWS SDK and create a dynamodb table in this account so that other accounts in the organization can't access it

Or maybe there are other alternatives to creating multiple accounts with their own tables under one main account, which will be the only one who will have access to each account's tables?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you use.

In case you use java (you can download java SDK from [here](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava.)), here is a link to [some java samples](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonDynamoDB/AmazonDynamoDBSample.java) on github that illustrate how to work with DynamoDB.

You must be signed up for the following services:

- AWS DynamoDB
- AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)

To run the examples you need to:

1. Create a credentials file in the location ~/.aws with name "credentials".
2. Save your Access Key ID and Secret Access Key:

   [default]

   aws_access_key_id =

   aws_secret_access_key =
3. Run the AmazonDynamoDBSample.java. The output will be in the console.

For more *getting started* examples (login, setting the request params etc) check the [InlineGettingStarted](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonEC2SpotInstances-GettingStarted/InlineGettingStartedCodeSampleApp.java).